# Call Dervied Class function Using Base Class object

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I’m trying to draw `CMFCRibbonTab` a with slightly small difference in which the text is a positionned a little bit higher.

To achieve that I’ve created a derived class called `DCRibbonTab` that extends `CMFCRibbonTab` and rewritten `virtual void OnDraw(CDC * pDC)` function as the following :

```
#pragma once
#include "StdAfx.h"

class DCRibbonTab : public CMFCRibbonTab
{
public:
    DCRibbonTab ();

    virtual ~DCRibbonTab ();
    virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pDC);
};

DCRibbonTab::~DCRibbonTab()
{
}

void DCRibbonTab::OnDraw(CDC * pDC)
{
    CMFCRibbonTab::OnDraw(pDC);
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    ASSERT_VALID(m_pParent);
    ASSERT_VALID(m_pParent->GetParentRibbonBar());

    if (m_rect.IsRectEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    COLORREF clrText = CMFCVisualManager::GetInstance()->OnDrawRibbonCategoryTab(pDC, this, m_pParent->IsActive() || GetDroppedDown() != NULL);
    COLORREF clrTextOld = pDC->SetTextColor(clrText);

    CRect rectTab = m_rect;
    CRect rectTabText = m_rect;

    pDC->DrawText(L"test", rectTabText, DT_CALCRECT | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);

    const int cxTabText = rectTabText.Width();
    const int cxTabTextMargin = max(4, (rectTab.Width() - cxTabText) / 2);

    rectTab.DeflateRect(cxTabTextMargin, 0);
    //rectTab.top += nPanelMarginTop;

    pDC->DrawText(GetParentCategory()->GetName(), rectTab, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
    pDC->SetTextColor(clrTextOld);
}
```

To be able to call the new `virtual void OnDraw(CDC * pDC)` of the `DCRibbonTab` I had to override the `void OnPaint()` of the `CMFCRibbonBar` Class as the following :

```
void DCRibbonBar::OnPaint()
{
    CMFCRibbonBar::OnPaint();

    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    int i = 0;

    CMemDC memDC(dc, this);
    CDC* pDC = &memDC.GetDC();

    for (i = 0; i < (int)m_arCategories.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        CMFCRibbonCategory* pCategory = m_arCategories[i];
        ASSERT_VALID(pCategory);

        if (pCategory->IsVisible())
        {
            CMFCRibbonTab * CurrentTab = pCategory->GetTab();

            //Need to Call DCRibbonTab OnDraw function using CMFCRibbonTab object CurrentTab

        }
    }
}
```

However, what I don’t seem to be able to achieve is to call the derived class `DCRibbonTab` `virtual void OnDraw(CDC * pDC)` using the base class object in which is `CMFCRibbonTab` object.

So, how can I call derived class function `DCRibbonTab` from base class object `CMFCRibbonTab`?

Comment: Show how `DCRibbonBar` class is incorporated in your project. Note that `OnDraw` is called in response to `WM_PAINT`. You can't simply create `DCRibbonBar` object and call the function randomly. Show more info about the architecture of your program. Most likely you have to derive a class from `CMFCVisualManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I was able to find the solution, using function overloading and Runtime polymorphism.
Here is the source code for the solution:

```
class DCRibbonTab : public CMFCRibbonTab
{
public:
    DCRibbonTab();
    virtual ~DCRibbonTab();
    void OnDraw(CDC* pDC, BOOL Redraw);
};

static const int nPanelMarginTop = 3;
// DCRibbonTab

DCRibbonTab:: DCRibbonTab ()
{
}

DCRibbonTab::~ DCRibbonTab ()
{
}

void DCRibbonTab::OnDraw(CDC* pDC, BOOL Redraw)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    ASSERT_VALID(pDC);
    ASSERT_VALID(m_pParent);
    ASSERT_VALID(m_pParent->GetParentRibbonBar());

    if (m_rect.IsRectEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    COLORREF clrText = CMFCVisualManager::GetInstance()->OnDrawRibbonCategoryTab(pDC, this, m_pParent->IsActive() || GetDroppedDown() != NULL);
    COLORREF clrTextOld = pDC->SetTextColor(clrText);

    CRect rectTab = m_rect;
    CRect rectTabText = m_rect;

    pDC->DrawText(m_pParent->GetName(), rectTabText, DT_CALCRECT | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_TOP);

    const int cxTabText = rectTabText.Width();
    const int cxTabTextMargin = max(4, (rectTab.Width() - cxTabText) / 2);

    rectTab.DeflateRect(cxTabTextMargin, 0);
    rectTab.top += nPanelMarginTop;

    pDC->DrawText(m_pParent->GetName(), rectTab, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_TOP);
    pDC->SetTextColor(clrTextOld);
}

void DCRibbonBar::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    int i = 0;

    CMemDC memDC(dc, this);
    CDC* pDC = &memDC.GetDC();

    CRect rectClip;
    dc.GetClipBox(rectClip);

    CRgn rgnClip;

    if (!rectClip.IsRectEmpty())
    {
        rgnClip.CreateRectRgnIndirect(rectClip);
        pDC->SelectClipRgn(&rgnClip);
    }

    pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

    CRect rectClient;
    GetClientRect(rectClient);

    OnFillBackground(pDC, rectClient);

    CFont* pOldFont = pDC->SelectObject(GetFont());
    ENSURE(pOldFont != NULL);
    // Draw tabs:
    CRect rectTabs = rectClient;
    rectTabs.top = m_rectCaption.IsRectEmpty() ? rectClient.top : m_rectCaption.bottom;
    rectTabs.bottom = rectTabs.top + m_nTabsHeight;

    COLORREF clrTextTabs = CMFCVisualManager::GetInstance()->OnDrawRibbonTabsFrame(pDC, this, rectTabs);

    for (i = 0; i < (int)m_arCategories.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        CMFCRibbonCategory* pCategory = m_arCategories[i];
        ASSERT_VALID(pCategory);

        if (pCategory->IsVisible())
        {
            DCRibbonTab *TempVnRibbonTab = new DCRibbonTab ();
            CMFCRibbonTab * TempMFCRibbonTab = pCategory->GetTab();
            TempDCRibbonTab = (DCRibbonTab*)TempMFCRibbonTab;
            TempDCRibbonTab->OnDraw(pDC, TRUE);
        }
    }
    // Draw elements on right of tabs:
    COLORREF clrTextOld = (COLORREF)-1;
    if (clrTextTabs != (COLORREF)-1)
    {
        clrTextOld = pDC->SetTextColor(clrTextTabs);
    }
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);
    pDC->SelectClipRgn(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DCRibbonTab : public CMFCRibbonTab
{
public:
    DCRibbonTab ();

    virtual ~DCRibbonTab ();
    void OnDraw(CDC* pDC) override;
};
```

This version should provide a clear error message if your version of the OnDraw() method isn't actually overriding the method defined in the base class. If you see that error, you know you need to double check whether you exactly matched the function signature in the base class, and of course confirm that the function is declared 'virtual' in the base.

If you don't get an error as a result of adding 'override', then calling the correct version should be simple:

```
CurrentTab->OnDraw(pDC);
```

Comment: That's not enough. You also have to wire up the correct C++ class instance to the control it represents. This is usually done by using the [DDX_Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04ab59a.aspx) function.